# Ctrl+V doesn't work in Pantheon Files

Tags: pantheon-files, pantheon

I don't understand how come I don't see anyone else complaining about this problem, is it only on my computer somehow, or is it a known removed feature?

But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste in Pantheon Files does not work to paste (neither a file nor a directory). I can tell that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for copying does work, because copying it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and then right-clicking to choose `Paste` does work. But hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> does nothing. Regardless of the method used to copy.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste into a file name when renaming (in Pantheon Files) works fine
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste into the path location (in Pantheon Files) works fine
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste in terminal works fine
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste works fine in all other programs (that I've tried so far).

How come, and are there any known suggestions to fix this?

Comment: Just tested it, works fine here. I do have a clipboard manager (clipit) installed, but I doubt that's why it works.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably just a bug in an old version

Try
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

If the problem still persists, try `sudo apt install --reinstall pantheon-files`

Hope this helps!

(It probably won't)

Comment: Versions later than revision 1902 should not have this problem. This was release in 2015. If you have a more recent version then please raise a bug report given details of the keyboard type / layout / locale etc.

Comment: You were right, it didn't help. I am running the newest everything, but I did manually reinstall `pantheon-files` anyway, and the issue is still here. I submitted a bug report as per Ben's suggestion.

Comment: are you sure you're not using a different keyboard layout? for example, shortcuts do not work for me when I'm switched to Russian on my keyboard